# How to edit google spreadsheet offline with Libre Office / Open Office

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, google-drive

I am working with my team on a spreadsheet on google docs.
Is it possible to edit this file offline (with e.g. LibreOffice) and sync and merge it later (like clone and push for github)? Platform independence is crucial.